# Are calls to signal() done across all threads?

Tags: c, signals

Are calls to signal() done across all threads in a process? Or do you have to call signal for each signal you want to catch per thread?

Thanks,
Chenz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this link on ["Requirements of the POSIX signal model"](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/posix-signal-model.xml),

> The basic concept behind the POSIX signal model is that
>
> signal handlers are a process resources; and
>
> signal masks are a thread resources

In other words, there can only be a single signal handler (for a particular signal) defined for the process, but you must set the signal mask in every thread.